# nw-builder - NWJS win64 app built using nw-builder does not run my code, only shows default NWJS splash screen

Tags: nwjs

I am attempting to build my first NWJS app for win64. I'm using MacOS 10.13.6 . After a rough start and updating npm and node, I finally ran a build which completed without errors. I downloaded the app package to my Windows machine, however when I run the .exe file, the app opens displaying the NWJS splash screen, instead of loading my code. Any ideas?

Root directory I'm running in:

```
10:50:50 : ~/ReolinkNWJS
ls
dist            icons           javascript      package-lock.json   package.json.TEMPLATE   src
html            images          node_modules        package.json        resources       styles
```

Do the build:

```
10:51:01 : ~/ReolinkNWJS
npm run prod

> ReolinkNWJS@0.0.1 prod
> nwbuild --platforms win64 --buildDir dist/ ./

Latest Version: v0.65.0
Using v0.65.0 (sdk)
Create cache folder in /Users/kevin/ReolinkNWJS/node_modules/nw-builder/cache/0.65.0-sdk
Using cache for: win64
Create release folder in /Users/kevin/ReolinkNWJS/dist/ReolinkNWJS/win64
```

Resulting win32 directory:

```
12:47:48 : ~/ReolinkNWJS
ls dist/ReolinkNWJS/win32
ReolinkNWJS.exe     d3dcompiler_47.dll  icudtl.dat      locales         notification_helper.exe nw_200_percent.pak  payload.exe     swiftshader     vk_swiftshader_icd.json
chromedriver.exe    debug.log       libEGL.dll      nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe    nw.dll          nw_elf.dll      pnacl           v8_context_snapshot.bin vulkan-1.dll
credits.html        ffmpeg.dll      libGLESv2.dll       node.dll        nw_100_percent.pak  nwjc.exe        resources.pak       vk_swiftshader.dll
```

I downloaded the complete win64 directory to my Windows machine, then executed the containing ReolinkNWJS.exe file.  As I stated, I only got the NWJS default splash screen, not my app.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ReolinkNWJS",
  "description": "Reolink Client App In NWJS Framework",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "icon": "icons/app.icns",
  "main": "html/main.html",
  "chromium-args": "--enable-logging=stderr --enable-spell-checking",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500,
    "position": "center"
  },
  "nodejs": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "nwbuild --platforms win64 --buildDir dist/ ./"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nw": "^0.12.0",
    "nw-builder": "^3.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for nwbuild part:

```
nwbuild --platforms win64 --buildDir dist/ ./
```

add in the flavour below may solve the issue:

```
--mode build
```

Comment: After fiddling for hours this was the message that solved it. For some reason --mode build is not described as a valid parameter in the nw-builder project, without it - it just runs the code in nwjs.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the issue you're encountering, since you're both using WINE: https://github.com/nwutils/nw-builder/pull/572#issuecomment-1144416689

Comment: Good sleuthing!  Looks like that could be it.  If I'm understanding this correctly, all I can do now is wait for the next release.

Comment: Apparently the release is out with the bugfix (3.7.1).  After updating I ran it and got tons more meaningful output, so it seems like something I needed to do.  However, it didn't fix my issue; I still get the same result when opening the app (NWJS default splash page.) :-(